# table saw cuts rough on left side, clean on right

Tags: technique, table-saw, cut

When cross-cutting softwood 2x4s, I find that the blade always cuts more cleanly on the right hand side of the blade than the left.  I am not talking about tear-out here, the cut is rough through the whole of the material.  As a result, I end up having to make the final cut with work-piece on the right.  But the saw (Evolution Rage 5s with 80 tpi blade) has a nice smooth mitre slide on the left but only a rather wobbly mitre slot on the right - I therefore have to compromise support for a clean cut.  Is it normal for a table saw to cut more cleanly on one side of the blade that the other (regardless of how the wood is supported), and if not, how do I fix this?  Thanks.

Comment: "*80 tpi blade*"  Do you mean an 80 tooth blade? What  kind of blade/teeth? The web site for the saw claims "*Cuts Steel, Aluminum & Wood With One Saw & One Blade!*", have you been cutting metal, how old/used is the blade.

Comment: The saw has a smaller bore size, if you changed blades to a standard bore blade did you use an adapter?   Blade review for the Evolution 5s  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaNOTA8kUeE

Comment: Sorry, yes that is 80 teeth.  It's not the blade that came with the saw it is a Saxton "TCT Circular Wood Mitre Saw Blade 255mm x 80T x 25.4mm Bore fits Evolution Rage Saws", which I believe is intended to be used with the Evolution saw without an adapter. No, I have not been cutting anything other than softwood and plywood with it, and it has had a few months of light use.

Comment: Does it exhibit the same behavior with other blades?  A test may help to shed light.

Comment: Is your fence parallel to the blade? (Measure from tooth at the back of the blade, then spin that same tooth forward and measure again.) My gut is that the fence is off, relative to the blade. Or the blade is off, relative to the table.

Comment: I hate to say this, but there's a decent chance this is the Evolution Rage, or at least the saw is a big contributing factor. They're widely considered Not Very Good (I'm being polite here, I've seen *pants* used to describe them). Now that said, why does this matter? You generally don't use a saw of this level to produce a finished cut, for finer work it's *only* used to rough-cut material, or it's for coarser work, and in either case the surface of the cut end really doesn't matter. You'll either A, be refining it by some means (*always*), or B, be using it as-is and it won't be an issue.

Comment: Generally, one wouldn't use a table saw to cross cut 2x4 stock anyway. It strikes me as being very hard to control a long piece as you're sliding it past the blade. I realize that when all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail, but you may want to reconsider your cutting options. You may well be _**safer**_ and get a better cut more easily by hand using a miter box and miter saw, or a circular saw and [Speed Square™](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Swanson-Tool-Company-Speed-Square/3048693)

Comment: @AlaskaMan I have now tried similar cuts with the blade that the saw came with, which is a 40 tooth all-purpose blade.  It cuts with the same quality on both sides of the blade, but the quality is slightly worse than the better quality side of the Saxton blade.  This suggests that there is an issue with the Saxton blade which causes one side of its cut to become rough, while maintaining good quality on the other side.  I see no visual difference between the sides of the blade though.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate These are cross cuts so I am not using the fence.  I don't have a great way of measuring how close to parallel the blade is to the mitre slide, but I estimate that the back of the blade may be closer to the mitre track than the front, by between 0.2 and 0.5mm in the case of the Saxton blade and around 0.1mm in the case of the Evolution blade, which I just tried.

Comment: @Graphus I am aware of the status of the evolution saw, but it was all that I could afford and fit in my limited space.  I agree that it is not the tool to be doing fine work with, but the symptoms of my problem seemed odd - for a newbie like me it seems strange that a blade would cut very cleanly on one side but rough on the other.  By the way, for future reference what would be considered a good job-site table saw?

Comment: @FreeMan point taken - I have recently acquired a circular saw and will probably be cutting down 2x4s on this from now on.  Again, a lot of the reason for my question is curiosity and finding out whether this could be the symptom of a bigger problem.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your helpful suggestions.

Comment: Your tests seem to indicate that there *is* an issue with the Saxton blade (the equal-quality cut surfaces made with the stock blade aren't definitive, but certainly strong evidence). So the thing to do now it examine each tooth on the rougher side, see if you can find broken carbide. Regardless of what you find though, basically I think this is going to come down to biting the bullet and contacting the maker, see what they'll do for you.

Comment: @Graphus, having lived in the UK for about a year some time ago, I recognize _pants_ as the epithet it truly is. Though, sometimes someone will disagree with your assertion something is _pants_ or a _pile of pants_ and call you a _big girls blouse_ for grousing about it. They might even ask you to _jog on_ if things get heated. (Though that last appears to be a recent import from Australia?)

Comment: It is likely that the blade is not parallel to the miter slot on the left side which pushes the wood into the back of the blade when cutting on the left side. In addition, there's a good likelihood that one of the teeth on your Saxon blade is out of alignment. There's some kind of anomaly in the teeth that carves up the left side cut surface. The alignment of the miter slot exasperates the problem.

Comment: Thanks very much everyone for your suggestions and comments.  I can't detect any defects on the blade by eye, but I will give it a thorough clean and try it again.  It may also be that I am also expecting too much from a budget jobsite saw - and that is fine, I just wanted to establish that I wasn't  missing anything obvious.

Comment: @Graphus I took your advice and contacted Saxton, describing the problem taking into account everyone's comments about my original question.  They quickly sent me a replacement blade which cuts equally well on both sides (and, as expected, better than the blade that comes with the saw). Thanks again for your help - by the way, I can't see a way of marking your comment as the accepted answer.

Comment: That's great, I'm so glad that was sorted for you! I can add an Answer for you to accept but frankly I don't need the points :-) Instead, how about you self-Answer your Question? This doesn't bend any rules, it is perfectly kosher here to do this. You can then select it as the accepted Answer, which is also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for my problem was to approach the blade manufacturer Saxton who promptly sent a new blade which cuts as expected.

The budget nature of the saw does not seem to have been an issue, and I think my measurements of blade orientation with respect to mitre slots were probably also a red herring.

Many thanks to everyone who contributed to this solution - this is a really helpful forum.